# How to throw an error if a field is being passed blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I have a function like the following and say some field is being passed blank, I need to throw some error like: "role is blank, please check". How would I do it (I'm passing five fields like: `ID`, `name`, `role`, `address`, `number`, etc..)?

```
def some_function
      @employee.with_lock do
        if @employee.update(permitted_attributes(@employee))
          render_json(@employee)
        else
          render json: ErrorSerializer.new(@employee), status: :unprocessable_entity
        end
      end
    end
```

Comment: can you please share your actual code. it may help the community to find a solution for your problem asap

Comment: This is my actual code, @ajay_speed

Comment: you may create a while loop with the condition to check whether the @id is empty:
condition:   while id.empty || id == nil  body: somefunction.call    #it calls the function again to get the id if the while condition is true    end.

Comment: It'd be great if you could share your comments in a code, please.

Comment: am not much clear with your code Mr. @alex . Where are you passing your arguments: ID, name, role, address, number, to?

Answer (score 3):

You usually add [validations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) to your model when you want to ensure that certain attributes are set.

In your example, the following might work:

```
# in app/models/employee.rb
validates :name, :role, :address, :number, presence: true
```